# cvBlob: OSX installation

Tags: opencv, makefile, cmake, osx-lion

Is someone able to give me a quick tutorial how to install [cvBlob](http://code.google.com/p/cvblob/) on osx 10.7 ? On their site they only mention linux and windows. A link would also be welcome, because i can't find any tutorial how to do this.

I tried to do it based on the linux tutorial and did the cmake with an extra entry with referes to my opencv folder. The cmake worked but When i do the make command, i get this error :

[image]

what do i have to do ?

the cmake:

[image]

Thx in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To give a quick overview how i got cvBlobs working :

1) download the latest [cvBlob](http://code.google.com/p/cvblob/)

2) Extract it

3) Navigate to cvBlob/cvBlob and open the CMakeLists.txt

4) Add this code :

```
if(APPLE)
   target_link_libraries(cvblob ${OpenCV_LIBS})
endif()
```

UNDERNEATH

```
add_library(cvblob SHARED ${cvBlob_CVBLOB})
```

5) open your cmake program and select the path to the folder where said cmake file is.
And select a path where you want your libs to be

6) Execute it

7) Open terminal, go to the folder

8) Then you get a makefile which you can `sudo make install`

9) To use the cvBlob in xcode you have to add the '`libcvblob.dylib`' to the other linker flags.

Answer (score 1):

About your

> No matching constructor for initialization of
>   'cvflann::LshIndexParams'

you might want to try changing your compiler to LLVM GCC 4.2 in XCode.

Comment: it is compiling using that compiler :)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `-m32` to CFLAGS/CXXFLAGS in cmake.

Comment: I've did the cmake for xcode. when i open this xcode project i try to compile this for 32 & 64 bit . When doing this i get this error : No matching constructor for initialization of 'cvflann::LshIndexParams'. and Call to function 'operator<<' that is neither visible in the template definition nor found by argument-dependent lookup .

Comment: Hey, it compiled correctly in console and failed to link because your opencv library is 32bit only. So I said how to fix this (compile cvblob also only for 32bit). Now you created Xcode project instead - I don't know why it doesn't even compile!

Comment: My opencv is not 32 bit only. It's not a problem with the architecture. It's a problem considering a path. Which one and why, i'm having a look at. I just wondered if someone did this before and if someone might be able to tell me which path this is etc ....

Comment: when you have problem with paths, you get something like 'library not found', and not 'symbol not found for architecture'.