# Adding third party libraries to an OpenCV project on Xcode

Tags: c++, xcode, opencv

I am new to the XCode environment so apologies if this sounds trivial.

I am trying to use a third party library using for OpenCV that helps me do some blob analysis, CCL etc. Hosted [here](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/cvBlobsLib)

I have searched a lot but there doesn't seem to be much documentation on how to go about adding and using these new libraries. I am using XCode 4.5.2, OpenCV 2.4.2.

When I simply add all the header files to the project folder and #include them in the source code, it fails to compile. I have also tried adding the "Header Paths" but it doesn't help. What am I missing?

I have tried to follow the instructions (compiling it using the terminal but it doesn't compile too) I am not clear on how or when exactly to use CMAKE.

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you using **CvBlob on google code** which is different from the one on willowgarage, I have got recently confused with this so [take a look at this question for alternative blob analysis libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13530054/blobs-with-opencv-which-library-is-best).

Moreover, CvBlob has also a good support community here. (Search on "[cvblobslib]" or on "[blob] [opencv]")

Comment: Thank you I ended up using the SimpleBlobDetector class and it seems to work fine. Although its a little slow with 640x480 images, resizing them solves the issue. More info on SimpleBlobDetector here :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8076889/tutorial-on-opencv-simpleblobdetector

Comment: Great! I've thought you'd like to see alternatives. Can you please indicate with voting-up or accepting if my answer was useful?

Answer (score 0):

Try this: [cvBlob: OSX installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8324155/cvblob-osx-installation)

Once you get it compiled, you need to include the library under Link Binary with Libraries in Build Phases. (This screenshot shows the `core`, `imgproc`, and `highgui` libraries. Your `cvBlob` library would go in the same place.)

Comment: This was great, I was able to install cvBlob and generate `libcvblob.dylib` there is another error within it. For now I have resorted to using the `SimpleBlobDetector`class.