# Cvblob for OSX Yosemite with Opencv 3.0

Tags: opencv, osx-yosemite

I cannot compile Cvblob for OSX Yosemite with Opencv 3.0 and I have read the following posts but still unable: [cvBlob: OSX installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8324155/cvblob-osx-installation)

I get this error:

```
cvblob.cpp:25:10: fatal error: 'cv.h' file
      not found
#include <cv.h>
         ^
```

How can I compile Cvblob for OSX Yosemite with Opencv 3.0?

Answer (score 0):

cvBlob is a deprecated c-api. Instead, please look into [SimpleBlobDetector](http://docs.opencv.org/ref/master/d0/d7a/classcv_1_1SimpleBlobDetector.html#gsc.tab=0) and [Contours](http://docs.opencv.org/ref/master/df/d0d/tutorial_find_contours.html#gsc.tab=0).